# Swift - Passing boolean between view controllers

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, viewcontroller

I have created a button. This is a customised button that show the image of a unchecked box. When the user click on the button, the image changes into a checked box, and vice versa when user click on it again. There is boolean value of true when box is checked and false when unchecked.

My objective is trying to pass this boolean value of true or false to another view controller to perform other tasks, when user click on the button.

Any advices? I do not think that i can use prepareforsegue using identifier.

**Class of the customised UIButton**

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox1: UIButton {

    //images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")

    //bool propety
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {



        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
            }else{
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK instead of moving the variable outside the class, create a new one called isCheckedGlobal or something different than isChecked.

```
import UIKit

var isCheckedGlobal = Bool() // !! Global Variable // You might need to change '= Bool()' to '= false' or '= true'

class CheckBox1: UIButton {

//images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")
let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")

//bool propety
var isChecked:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if isChecked == true{
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }else{
            self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {



    if(sender == self){
        if isChecked == true{
            isChecked = false 
            isCheckedGlobal = false // !! Set variable's value
        }else{
            isChecked = true
            isCheckedGlobal = true // !! Set variable's value
        }
    }
}

}
```

Then use isCheckGlobal in the other class to access the value of isChecked

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a global variable ? Especially when your `isChecked` property, from your button, is public you can access it.

From there, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method.

**Checkbox :** Keep it like it was

**ViewController :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myCheckBox: CheckBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Make sure you created the segue in the storyboard and match it's identifier name
        if (segue.identifier == "firstToSecondVCSegue") {
            let secondVC : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            secondVC.isChecked = myCheckBox.isChecked
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController :**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var isChecked : Bool?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("isChecked status : \(self.isChecked)")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: I am trying to pass the boolen value from customised UIButton from viewcontroller2 back to viewcontroller1. I cannot use a prepareforsegue because there is no identifier for the button, i.e. _segue.identifier_ Tell me if i'm wrong...

Comment: 1/2: Well, your `@IBOutlet var myCheckBox: CheckBox!` has to be in the secondVC. Where you'll still access it the same way. The segue and identifier has to do with the VC itself not the button. From there, what you would like to do is _unwind the segue_ (from where you came) and _passing data_. This can be done in few steps : In your code, create an IBAction function with a `UIStoryboardSegue` in parameters. Then, in you storyboard, link a _back button_ to the Exit (orange square on top of VC) selecting your IBAction. In the function you should be able to access the segue.sourceViewController.

Comment: 2/2: I haven't done it in Swift yet. You might find example here (or google) to unwind segue with data passing. Let us know if you manage to do it. I'll try to give some code later on if you didn't.

Comment: My checkbox is a customised class _checkbox2_. Checkbox is in Viewcontroller2, but this button uses _checkbox2_ class. I have a submit button to will segue into Viewcontroller1, which i can use that as an identifier but my boolean value is inside _checkbox2_ class, so i cannot use segue method to pass the boolean value into Viewcontroller1. Because boolean value is not inside Viewcontroller2.

Comment: You can pass data from one view controller to another. For example, you can set a Bool of your secondVC from the firstFC (during prepareForSegue). Inversely, you can retrieve a Bool from your secondVC in your firstVC (using the Exit (i.e. unwind segue)). See my other answer (not comment), it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, in addition to my previous comment and yours, here is an example with a UILabel being changed after unwinding the segue.

**Checkbox :**

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {

    //images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")

    //bool propety
    var isChecked:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if (self.isChecked) {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        if (sender == self) {
            if isChecked == true {
                isChecked = false
            } else {
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewController :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isChecked : Bool?
    @IBOutlet var isCheckedLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Here, you could pass the status each time you access the secondVC.
    }

    @IBAction func unwindFromSecondVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let secondVC : SecondViewController = segue.sourceViewController as SecondViewController
        self.isChecked = secondVC.myCheckBox.isChecked

        self.isCheckedLabel.text = self.isChecked?.description
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController :**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myCheckBox: CheckBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // You can do stuff here if needed.
        // But in your case, see firstVC.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

**Storyboard :**
[image: Storyboard]

Does it answer your problem ?